# Odoo 10 C transaction data archiving

Tags: archive, odoo-10

hello is there a module that allows you to archive data from several modules at the same time (sale, purchase, invoice...) on Odoo 10 CE?

a bit like the record_archiver does in ODOO versions 7,9 and 11.
https://odoo-community.org/shop/product/records-archiver-4101?version=9&page=4

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this module which is in 9 & 11 version then simply go for migration of this module.(into V10)

So you can brush up your skills with migration also.

Comment: thank you for your answer,Saumil. Isn't there another solution if I don't want to migrate?

Comment: Another solution, make a one Cron and  call your python function to archive multiple records at the same time.

Comment: I thought about that, but I think it can create inconsistencies later on if you don't manage relationships well. 
that's why I'm looking for modules that can do that, I don't have enough skill to go there.

Comment: Use this:-
https://github.com/saumil001/migrated-modules

Comment: Helped this module?